# Is it possible to disable Spring Cloud Sleuth header propagation based on destination URL?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-sleuth

We're using Brave's `ExtraFieldPropagation` feature to propagate custom fields (e.g. an internal-only request identifier) between services as HTTP headers.

Some of our services make requests to external services using a `RestTemplate` or Feign client in the course of processing a request. Since Sleuth enhances all `RestTemplate` beans and Feign clients with the propagation feature, this means that external services receive the internal-only headers, which I'd like to avoid.

I know of two workarounds that allow me to avoid this behavior, both of which are flawed:

- Instantiate a client object manually as opposed to using a `@Bean` so that Sleuth does not add an interceptor. The downside I see here is that developers have to remember to follow this pattern to avoid leaking information, and this is difficult to enforce.
- Add an interceptor that removes these headers from outgoing requests. The downsides here are that a) I need separate interceptors for `RestTemplate` and Feign clients (not a huge deal); b) it looks like Feign client interceptors do not have a way to influence order of execution (see javadoc [here](https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign/blob/master/core/src/main/java/feign/RequestInterceptor.java)), so I can't guarantee that the new interceptor will run last / after the Sleuth one.

Is there a way to customize Sleuth (e.g. via some kind of injector bean) such that, prior to injecting headers in an outgoing HTTP request, I can reason about the destination of the request? I saw documentation regarding [custom injector beans](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/1.3.x/multi/multi__customizations.html), but it appears those no longer exist in spring boot >= 2. I can't seem to find an equivalent construct in Brave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can unsample a given URL which means that the headers will be propagated but not sent to Zipkin. You can't disable instrumentation for only some of the URLs cause we're instrumenting all of the components that are registered as beans.

Comment: Thanks so much for taking a look, Marcin!

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. I don't want that sleuth is adding header variables when an external api call is made. @Marcin Grzejszczak Is it still not possible to prevent that by configuration?

Comment: Yes, you can not register that RestTemplate as a bean or you can remove the listener from RestTemplate bean.